# System.ServiceModel disappear

Tags: c#

After installing .Net Framework 4.0 it seems like I cannot find System.ServiceModel in .Net tab through "Add Reference..." by using VS2008. But you can see it and add it in VS2010 version.

Can someone tell me why, and how I can have both version, and still can use it in VS2008?

Thanks

Comment: I can see it on my machine. It's at "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll"

Comment: Can you see if you have the assembly in the location that ChrisF mentioned in the comment above?  Also, do you see the assembly in your GAC (windows explorer to c:\windows\assembly)?  I see the System.ServiceModel.dll assembly in both places I mentioned.

Comment: ChrisF,
Thanks for the response. I have ..\v3.0\en\*.xml. Basically they are all xml files, and I cannot find any dll there.

Comment: D Hoerster,
Thanks for the response as well. I did see the System.ServiceModel inside GAC. But not in the place ChrisF mentioned.

This only happens after I installed .Net Framework4.0 and VS2010.

Comment: Just curious about where dlls are located when you click "Add References ..." inside VS2008, VS2010 IDE. Does it look up 1). C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\... 2) GAC ? to pick up all the dlls.

Comment: Regarding the XML files, do you see any DLLs in the \v3.0 directory?  The '\en' subdirectory contain XML files that have intellisense files.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 command prompt (usually under All Programs - Visual Studio 20XX - Visual Studio Tools) and type in:

> gacutil /l System.ServiceModel

What do you get back?

If you have VS2008 & VS2010 installed, you should see two items listed (from my Win7 machine that has VS2008 & VS2010 installed):

> The Global Assembly Cache contains the
>   following assemblies:
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Number of items = 2

You should also see if you have System.ServiceModel.dll in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0` (from ChrisF's comment above).  The GAC should be referencing the assembly from there.  If you have the DLL there, but don't see it in the GAC, you can add it as a reference from the Add Reference dialog just by browsing to it.

Let me know what you see.  I'll try to get back ASAP.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know what happened. After I uninstalled VS2010, and .Net Framework 4.0. It all works now, and I see the dll in 2 places like ChrisF mentioned. Hmmm ...